# An attempt to solve an exercise (a lemma for an alternative proof of Schröder-Bernstein theorem)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In his *Naive Set Theory*, Halmos gave an exercise and stated that it can be used to prove Schröder-Bernstein theorem:

> **EXERCISE**. Suppose that $f$ is a mapping from $X$ into $Y$ and $g$ is a mapping from $Y$ into $X$. Prove that there exist subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, such that $f(A) =B$ and $g(Y- B) =X-A$. This result can be used to give a proof of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem that looks quite different from the one above.

I tried to construct the set $A$ by selecting elements of $X$ that are not in the range of $g$. But the image under $f$ of any such element will not be included in $B$ and then I may " lose" other elements of $X$ in the process of going from $Y-B$ to $X-A$. So I tried to think of a method to accommodate the loss if it occurs but I got stuck.

After trying to look for a hint I saw a beautiful result in Smullyan's "Set theory and the continuum problem" where he mentioned the fixed point lemma which is then applied to the set-valued function:  $C\mapsto X-g(Y-f(C))$ to get the required result to be used then in the proof of the theorem. There is also a [similar solution on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4487717/1195730).

My question: is there another way to solve it?

Comment: I assume you’re referring to the Knaster-Tarski theorem. You could look over the proof of that theorem and specialise the proof to this particular case to see if there are any insights.

Comment: If you are willing to use Choice, apply Zorn to the set of subsets $C$ of $X$ with $g(Y-f(C))\cap C=\emptyset$