# Proof of existence of subsets $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ such that $f(A)=B \,$ and $g(Y-B)=X-A$ without using fixed points?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I encountered the following exercise in Halmos *Naive Set Theory*

> Suppose that $f$ is a mapping from $X\,$ into $\,Y$ and $\,g\,$ is a mapping from $Y$ into $X$. Prove that there exist subsets $A$ and $B\,$ of $X\,$ and $\,Y$ respectively, such that $f(A)=B\,$ and $g(Y-B)=X-A$.

I already found a [link](https://books.google.de/books?id=kvoaoWOfqd8C&lpg=PP1&ots=Jp46YyLHec&dq=mathematical%20foundations%20of%20computational%20engineering&pg=PA152#v=onepage&q&f=false) to a solution of this problem on this website but the presented solution there mentions complete lattices and fixed points, which although not unfamiliar to me, have not been mentioned in Halmos book. Therefore I think there must be an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\Phi:\mathcal{P}(X)\to \mathcal{P}(X)$ the function such that $\Phi(A)=X-g(Y-f(A))$.

It's not difficult to check that if $A\subseteq B$ then $\Phi(A)\subseteq\Phi(B)$.

Define $\mathcal{S}=\{A\in \mathcal{P}(X) | \Phi(A)\subseteq A\}$ and $A_0=\bigcap\limits_{A\in\mathcal{S}}A$.

Since $A_0\subseteq A$ for all $A\in \mathcal{S}$, then $\Phi(A_0)\subseteq \Phi(A)\subseteq A$ for all $A\in \mathcal{S}$.

Thus from the definition of $A_0$ and intersecting over all the $A\in \mathcal{S}$, you get $\Phi(A_0)\subseteq A_0$.

And from this we get $A_0\in\mathcal{S}$ and
$$\Phi(\Phi(A_0))\subseteq \Phi(A_0)\subseteq A_0$$
So $\Phi(A_0)\in \mathcal{S}$. But then $A_0=\bigcap\limits_{A\in\mathcal{S}}A\subseteq \Phi(A_0)$ since $\Phi(A_0)$ is one of the sets being intersected.

From all of the above we conclude that $\Phi(A_0)=A_0$ and thus,
$$A_0=\Phi(A_0)=X-g(Y-f(A_0))$$

$$X-A_0=g(Y-f(A_0))$$

Which is what you wanted.

Comment: A brief remark on the reason why $\Phi(A_0)\subseteq A_0$: obviously $\forall A \in S \;\Phi(A) \in S$ and  $\Phi(A) \subseteq A$, so we have both $A_0=\bigcap A$ and $A_0=\bigcap \Phi(A)$, but $\Phi(A_0)=\Phi(\bigcap A) \subseteq \bigcap \Phi(A)=A_0$, ergo as desired.